# Is there any other signature mechanism like ECDSA to verify the signed message if its tampered or not?

Tags: security, testing, cryptography, hash, ecdsa

I would like to know if there are other signature verification methods other than ECDSA, to verify the message (eg., string, number) signed by a signer.
Actually if there are alternative algorithms that can be implemented using solidity, that are most preferred than the ECDSA, to check if the sent message is correct or tampered by verifying the signer address, Which one will have the best performance based on the comparative analysis?

Could you please advice?

Answer (score 0):

ECDSA is the only natively supported signature verification algorithm.

It should be possible to program other algorithms in the ethereum virtual machine. Although they might not be as performant as ECDSA or feasible to execute on-chain.

While ECDSA can be used to verify signatures it doesn't deal with message tampering. There are other algorithm used to achieve that feature, in Ethereum you should be able to implement HMAC for example.